# How can I use commas in number inserts so it doesn't break my input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculator, date-arithmetic

I have created a calculation form and have been running some A B testing with it, I noticed that many people in a field asking for "Total Donors" will try to put `"10,000"` instead of `10000`.

Is there anyway I can make it so commas can be put in, but then overlooked and unread in JS? So it displays `10,000` to the user, but my script still reads it as `10000`. It has to be done on multiple fields, is there a global solution to this?

I don't know enough JS to figure out how to even start attacking this problem. I'd imagine that it would have to be some type of code that computes a string value, then pops the commas inside so it is returned as a number.

The field I am using for an example also adds bonus points to the total based on the number put in. Since the calc form is going to be used by agencies of all sizes we need to add this to level it out so larger companies with more donors have more points to get, as smaller companies are neither penalized for their total score.

total score for small companies: `400`

total score for companies where bonus is applies: `420`

Bonus totals:

```
• val < 10001 = + 0
• val >= 10001 and < 25001 = + 10
• val >= 25001 and < 50000 = + 15
• val >= 50000 = + 2
```

**My input looks like this (Split up for readability):**

```
<fieldset class="webform-component-fieldset form-wrapper" id="webform-component-constituent-base">

    <legend><span class="fieldset-legend">Constituent Base</span></legend>

    <div class="fieldset-wrapper"><div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield" id="webform-component-constituent-base--total-constituents">

    <label for="edit-submitted-constituent-base-total-constituents">Total Number of constituents in your database </label>

    <input type="text" id="edit-submitted-constituent-base-total-constituents" name="submitted[constituent_base][total_constituents]" value="" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text" />
    </div>
    </div></fieldset>
```

**My calculations for this field**

```
var donorTotal = jQuery("#edit-submitted-constituent-base-total-constituents").val();
    if(donorTotal)
    {
        donorTotal = parseFloat(donorTotal);
    }
    else
    {
        donorTotal = 0;
    }

    grade += getBonusDonorPoints(donorTotal);

    // End total # of donors
```

**Bonus Points Function:**

```
function getBonusDonorPoints(val)
{
    if(val < 10001)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if(val >= 10001 && val < 25001)
    {
        return 10;
    }
    else if(val >= 25001 && val < 50000)
    {
        return 15;
    }
    else if(val >= 50000)
    {
        return 20;
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help you guys can give me in pointing me towards and answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So replace the comma and make sure you are working with a number and not a string.

```
Number(jQuery("#edit-submitted-constituent-base-total-constituents").val().replace(/,/g,""));
```

Comment: I'd use the regex `/,/g` to match *all* commas instead of just the first.

Comment: Works great! Thanks for the help @epascarello! *Also* thanks for pointing out the `/,/g` @boxmein! That was going to be my question since I noticed it only read the first one. 

Everything seems to be working smoothly. (Will accept answer in 5mins)

Answer (score 0):

I would attack this problem by removing anything that is not a number. This works great for fields like SSNs, phone numbers, zipcodes, and whatnot and is good for internationalization of these sorts of field.

```
function justTheNumbers(s) {
  return s.replace(/\D/g, '');
}
```

Comment: Already solved it, since this would only accept numbers, the above solution works well for me. Saving this snippet for future reference though :)